# NetworkManager icon on notification area is not present

Tags: linux, fedora, notifications, networkmanager

I have noticed that recently the NetworkManager icon is not present on the notification area plugin on my XFCE panel after every fresh login; however, I am able to see its notifications and it in fact still connects to the network. What I do next is remove the notification area plugin, add it again and there it is, the NetworkManager icon appears normally.

I think this is an issue with the notification area plugin for XFCE, but I've tried:

- Reinstall the plugin via yum
- Uninstall and install the plugin again via yum
- Remove its . (dot) files from the local user account
- Look for the "managed=false" setting on /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and set it to "true" (such setting wasn't there in the first place)

I have to say that once it's shown, I can suspend/hibernate and it'll still be there, but if I log off it won't show upon the next login.

Why does this happen? How can I make it to show normally on every login?

I am running Fedora 21 XFCE with kernel 3.19.3-200.fc21.x86_64.

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug in gtk 3.16.1](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/44504) and a patched version is due to be released sometime around 4/14/2015. In the meantime try running `xfce4-panel -r` (which restarts/reloads) the panel should get it to reappear if it doesn’t run `ps auxww |grep nm-applet` if it doesn’t show up there then you have bigger issue (aka it’s not running).
If not running try any of the following steps:

1. `sudo systemctl restart lightdm`. Reloads *all* of Xserver; effectively logging you out and back in.
2. `rm -rf  ~/.config/xfce*` then logout and back in. This regenerates and reloads a virgin instance; any custom settings highly advised to be backed up first.
3. `sudo yum/dnf reinstall xfce-desktop-environment` then logout and back in.

Answer (score 1):

I had a few issues with the networkmanager, though not that one... I doubt that XFCE is the culprit though. If that were the case, many would be complaining. And the same problem has been reported for other window managers.
Is nm-applet running on your system?

Here are some interesting suggestions:

- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=99125 Checking if the nm-applet is actually running. (`nm-applet --sm-disable &`)
- https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=169668 Check if the applet isn't showing, or just invisible - it may just be the icon which isn't visible - the button may actually be there.
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1621690 Check  if `dbus` is running correctly (`sudo /etc/init.d/dbus restart` in case of Ubuntu)

Comment: External links can become unavailable, in which case the answer loses its value.  Please include the essential information in your answer and use the links for attribution and further reading.  At least include the gist of the link here so the reader has a clue what they will be looking at, or what to pursue or research if the link breaks.

Comment: @fixer1234: What are the legal precedents on copying possibly copyright protected information on another site without permission of the author?

Comment: Good point.  The idea isn't to plagiarize someone else's work.  See [this on fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) (and the kinds of links you used aren't copyrighted material).  There isn't a need or desire to republish entire works, just excerpt or paraphrase the essential information (there is no copyright on information).  The link attributes credit and  provides the source.  For copyrighted material, authors actually appreciate and encourage this type of exposure and citation.

Comment: @fixer1234. In this case the references are from forums, and are probably not representative for problem cases (I'll try to amend the above). Copyright is just one possibility - with the multitude of licenses currently in vogue, I don't think it's fair to request of collaborators to do 'background checks' on each of the references they use. By the way, what is the mean usefulness lifetime of any of the answers? Did anyone compare that with the average lifetime of a reference target?

Comment: It's a good sign that you are considering this. Just for your peace of mind, information is not licensed or protected, and for any kind of content that is protected, there is no legal or ethical issue with the length or type of excerpt/citation that would be done here. There is never a need for "background checks" or prior approval. To your last point, links go stale at a surprising rate, even at major sites like Microsoft's and other manufacturer's own web sites. OTOH, content here can have amazing longevity (still questions on Windows 98, 95, and earlier, & hardware from the stone age).